# Limit in which terms involve n

Tags: limits

Limit n goes to infinity $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+......+\frac{1}{n+2n}$.

Well the answer came out log[3].. but i dont know how.?
I am trying for MCA.

please don't tell complete answer just a hint would be useful

Comment: Just to clarify, you do you mean
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\frac{1}{n+i}$$

Comment: no in my question i goes from 1 to 2n

Comment: Okay, but the rest is right? Interesting, I've never seen this problem before. I was just asking because I found this a little hard to read.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Note that

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{2n} \frac{1}{n + i} = \sum_{i = 0}^{2n} \frac 1 n \cdot \frac 1 {1 + i/n} = \sum_{i =0}^{2n} \frac 1 n f\left(\frac i n\right)$$

for $f(x) = \frac 1 {1 + x}$. Do you recognize a Riemann sum?

Comment: ok as definite integral as sum of limits thanxx

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture of $y=1/x$. Use the picture to note that
$$\int_k^{k+1} \frac{dx}{x} \lt \frac{1}{k}\lt \int_{k-1}^k \frac{dx}{x}.$$
Thus
$$\int_n^{3n}\frac{dx}{x}\lt \sum_n^{3n}\frac{1}{k}\lt \int_{n-1}^{3n-1} \frac{dx}{x}.$$
Evaluate the integrals, and Squeeze.